# Question on notation (t-statistics)

Tags: notation

Which one is correct:

"Coefficients are shown in bold. *T*-statistics are shown in parentheses."

or

"Coefficients are shown in bold. *t*-statistics are shown in parentheses."

Or are both correct?

The question is whether to capitalize the *t*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that the convention that $t$ statistics are presented using lower case for $t$ is immensely more important than any grammatical convention about capitalising the first word of a sentence.

I am old enough to remember typists trying to interpret academic authors' handwriting or trying to correct what they thought was wrong (and sometimes they were right). In this century, the main risk is that a copy editor for a publisher tries to fix what is not broken.

Obvious but possibly helpful: recasting any sentence to avoid such a clash is always an option.

> Coefficients are shown in bold and $t$-statistics are shown in
> parentheses.